# Truefully vs Truthfully -- interchangeable?

Tags: synonyms

Are *truefully* and *truthfully* essentially the same?

Does one have an implication, intonation, or standard use
that the other does not?

I know [from Oxford's online dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/trueful)
that *trueful* is an actual word.
However I can't tell if it has a history, 
or if they've included it due to common use (or perhaps misuse?)

Comment: Well, the explanation that it's from Middle English (1150–1470) would imply some sort of history.

Comment: Most people would think that truefully was a typo, and would want to correct it to truthfully.  That includes my spell checker!

Comment: "The wheel spins because of its truefulness".  ???

Comment: @Carl a wheel is true when it forms a perfect circle without deformations. [When is a wheel considered true?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/29445/4313)

Comment: I think *trueful* should be revived as a portmanteau of *true* and *rueful*, to be used for describing *the regretful expression of a fact*.

Comment: I don’t really understand this. You link to the definition of _trueful_, which says “Loyal, faithful”. If you look up _truthful_ in the same dictionary, you’ll see that it means something completely different. So clearly they’re not the same, essentially or non-essentially…

Comment: "Truefully" isn't word I've ever heard in spoken English. You might find it in a dictionary, but on the street? Not so much...

Comment: @Carl If we're talking about wheels, "trueness" is more commonly found than "truefulness", by about 1000:1. https://www.google.com/search?q=wheel+"trueness" vs https://www.google.com/search?q=wheel+"truefulness"

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The OED says trueful is rare; it says truefully is obsolete.  The first, the OED notes, was formed in English (c. 1325) from "true" (meaning faithful in the sense in which we use it today with reference to, for example, romantic relationships).

The primary definition of trueful in the OOD (to which you link) is "loyal, faithful", which is of course different from "honest," the basic meaning of truthful.  Thus they are in no way "essentially the same" or "interchangeable."

Answer (score 16):

"Trueful" may be in a dictionary, but it is a very very very unusual word (I don't remember ever having encountered it, and I've certainly never said it).

GloWbE, the corpus of Global Web-based English, has precisely 4 instances of "trueful" and 4 of "truefully". Contrast that with 8608 for "truthful" and 3920 for "truthfully".

I strongly suspect it is a mishearing of "truthful", but it may have entered some people's normal language.